# Why can thinking make a headache worse?

Tags: neurology, headache, concentration, mental-exhaustion, obsessive-compulsive

I sometimes get headaches where if I try and ignore them and continue with my work, they get so bad I feel sick and have to have a lie down until it passes. I've found that the best thing to do is stop working the moment one starts to develop and get away from the PC.

But I wondered, why/how *can* concentrating/thinking make a headache worse? What's the link?

Comment: Are you sure the issue is thinking and not the effect of the PC screen on your eyes? If you switch to reading a book, or thinking hard away from the screen, what is the impact on the headache?